# When parsing a C header file in IDA, is there a preprocessor symbol I can use to detect it?

Tags: ida

[IDA has the ability to parse C header files](https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-141-parsing-c-files/) (by now a secondary option based on Clang also exists). It is useful to get structs and enums into your database via the Local Types view.

**Question:** *Aside* from the `CC_PARMS` setting in `ida.cfg` mentioned by Igor in the above article, is there a built-in preprocessor define that I can rely upon to accommodate IDA?

I am looking for something like `__cplusplus` but for detecting IDA and perhaps even the IDA major version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [IDC: Predefined symbols](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1165.shtml) (emphasis mine):

---

The following symbols are predefined in the IDC preprocessor:

```
  _NT_           IDA is running under MS Windows
  _LINUX_        IDA is running under Linux
  _MAC_          IDA is running under Mac OS X
  _UNIX_         IDA is running under Unix (linux or mac)
  _EA64_         64-bit version IDA
  _QT_           GUI version of IDA (Qt)
  _GUI           GUI version of IDA
  _TXT_          Text version of IDA
  _IDA_VERSION_  The current IDA version. For example: "8.3"
  _IDAVER_       The current, numerical IDA version. For example: "830" means v8.3
```

**These symbols are also defined when parsing C header files.**

---